# How to check for character files in a directory

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, file-attributes

I got this code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674287/c-checking-the-type-of-a-file-using-lstat-and-macros-doesnt-work)

```c
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char* folder="/dev/input";                                     //folder to open

    DIR* dir_p;
    struct dirent* dir_element;
    struct stat file_info;

    // open directory
    dir_p=opendir(folder);

    // show some info for each file in given directory
    while(dir_element = readdir(dir_p)) {

        lstat(dir_element->d_name, &file_info);          //getting a file stats

        puts(dir_element->d_name);                       // show current filename
        printf("file mode: %d\n", file_info.st_mode);

        // print what kind of file we are dealing with
        if (file_info.st_mode == S_IFDIR) puts("|| directory");
        if (file_info.st_mode == S_IFREG) puts("|| regular file");
        if (file_info.st_mode == S_IFLNK) puts("|| symbolic link");
        if (S_ISCHR(file_info.st_mode)) puts("|| character file");
    }
}
```

I modified it a little bit so that it prints if files in `/dev/input` are character files or not. But when I run this(even with sudo) it only prints the file name, file mode and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `file_info.st_mode` are bit-fields, so you should check if individual bits are set with the `&` operator.

That is,

```
if (file_info.st_mode & S_IFDIR) puts("|| directory");
```

However, using `S_ISXXX` macros is more explicit as you did for the last one.

Second, `dir_element->d_name` contains only the basename of the path. Hence, you should prepend `folder` to it before feeding it into `lstat`. If you have checked the return value of `lstat`, you could have known that it didn't succeed.
So you can do something like

```c
// 2 is for '/' and '\0'
char *full_path = malloc(strlen(folder) + strlen(dir_element->d_name) + 2;
// please do check if malloc failed
// I'm sure FULL_PATH has sufficient memory, but use strncpy/strncat if in doubt
strcpy(full_path, folder);
strcat(full_path, "/");
strcat(full_path, dir_element->d_name);
lstat(full_path, &file_info);
free(full_path);
```